# ArrayList using Object as Type

Tags: java, arraylist

**Background:** I am fooling around in Java. I created a class called Animal which tracks the name, age, sex and numberOfAnimals Created. It has constructors, accessor methods, a method to printNumAnimals (outputs static variable numberOfAnimals) and printAnimals(outputs the instance variable values).

When I instantiate a new Animal object in my Main method I can use constructors or the set methods to set the values of the instance variables. All works well!

**Problem:** When I create an ArrayList of Animal objects it works. It creates the ArrayList but when I output it outputs the reference to the animal objects as: [animal.Animal@15db9742, animal.Animal@6d06d69c, animal.Animal@7852e922] instead of the individual field values. As you can see in the code below I do a simple sysout of animals which is the ArrayList. I know I can set an Iterator to loop through the ArrayList but I want to output the values of the fields not just the reference to the object. How can I achieve that?

I am ommitting the Animal class code as this is a very simple class with private fields and public getters and setters. Please see Main Class below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import animal.Animal;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*
        Animal animal= new Animal();
        animal.setName("");
        animal.setAge(-2);
        animal.setSex("Jake");

        animal.printAnimal();
        Animal.printNumAnimals();
        */

        ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();

        Animal animal;

        animal = new Animal();
        animal.setName("Fido");
        animal.setAge(3);
        animal.setSex("Male");
        animals.add(animal);

        animal = new Animal();
        animal.setName("Fifi");
        animal.setAge(1);
        animal.setSex("Female");
        animals.add(animal);

        animal = new Animal();
        animal.setName("Jake");
        animal.setAge(2);
        animal.setSex("female");
        animals.add(animal);

        Animal.printNumAnimals();
        System.out.println(animals);

    }

}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29

Comment: Hi JB, I apologize if this is a duplicate. I searched the knowledge base and could not find the solution. I may have searched incorrectly. I thank you for the link to the api docs. This also helped

Answer (score 2):

You have to override the `Animal#toString()` method.

You could have something like this in your `Animal` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
     return String.format("Animal: name=%s, age=%s, sex=%s", name, age, sex);
}
```

Comment: Dude, thank you so much! That override of the toString method did it! You are a star!